# Meaning of 'V' in MCVE differs between pages

Tags: bug, status-completed

The [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page says:

> For help with this, read How to create a Minimal, Complete, **Valid** Example.

However the [linked page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is titled:

> How to create a Minimal, Complete, and **Verifiable** example

One of these should be fixed...

Comment: Isn't something that's valid verifiable?  (I do agree; this should be corrected.)

Comment: @Makoto: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verification_and_validation